# Twisted Internationalization

Tags: python, i18n, twisted

I'm not particularly Python savy and [recently wrote](https://github.com/megawac/iris/commit/fed82b8a6a4c9168fda4ee12a657fde5bddfc337) a `LocalizationEngine` for `Twisted`.

The strategy I implemented was to make a dictionary from `base.json` and then merge with any existing files set in the `Accept-Language` set in the URL (or cookie). For instance the `Accept-Language` of `en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6` would merge `base.json, en.json, en-US.json` in that order. The folder layout looks like this:

[image: folder layout]

```
from twisted.web import resource, server, static, error as http_error
import json
import os

## load the JSON resource from the path and return the parse obj (dict in this case)
def getJSON(path):
  file = open(path)
  data = json.load(file)
  file.close()
  return data

class LocalizationEngine(resource.Resource):
  isLeaf = True
  localePath = "static/lang/"

  def __init__(self, prefix):
    pass

  def render_GET(self, request):
    return self.getLocale(request)

  def getLocale(self, request):
    """
    Request a localization and respond with json object of appropriate locale
    """
    setLocales = request.getCookie("i18n") #preferred locale (todo implement)?
    locales = []
    if setLocales:
      locales = json.load(setLocales)
    else:
      lang_header = request.headers.get("Accept-Language", "en") # for example en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
      locales = [locale.split(';')[0] for locale in lang_header.split(',')]

    basePath = self.localePath + (request.args.get("path", [""])[0])
    if not basePath.endswith("/"):
      basePath += "/"

    if not os.path.exists(basePath):
      raise http_error.NoResource().render(request)

    lang = getJSON(basePath + "base.json")

    # reverse so specificity overrides
    for locale in reversed(locales):
      path = basePath + locale + ".json"
      if os.path.exists(path):
        lang.update(getJSON(path))

    cache(request)
    request.write(json.dumps(lang))
    request.finish()
    return True
```

**cache.py**

```
from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time as format_date
from datetime import date, timedelta
from time import mktime

'''
   Sets the cache headers for a (static resource) request
'''
def cache(request, expires=30, public=True):
    #set expires header
    expiry = (date.today() + timedelta(expires)).timetuple()
    request.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders("expires" , [format_date(mktime(expiry))])

    #set cache control
    cache_control = "max-age=" + str(int(60*60*24*expires))
    if public:
        cache_control += ", public"
    else:
        cache_control += ", private"
    request.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders("cache-control", [cache_control])

    return request
```

A code review of the above implementation or suggesting an existing Twisted/Python Internationalization implementation (couldn't find one) would be great answers :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Twisted, 
and also cannot recommend existing internationalization implementations,
but I can code review in terms of Python in general.

You are not following [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),
the official coding style guide of Python.
The coding style violations are not so bad but they are noticeable.
I won't comment on those one by one,
I suggest to give the doc a good read and follow it.

It's nice that you documented this method with a comment:

> ```
> ## load the JSON resource from the path and return the parse obj (dict in this case)
> def getJSON(path):
>   file = open(path)
>   data = json.load(file)
>   file.close()
>   return data
> ```

Why not go all the way and document with a proper docstring?
Also, closing files manually is old-fashioned. 
The recommend way is simpler and better:

```
def getJSON(path):
    """
    load the JSON resource from the path and return the parse obj (dict in this case)

    @param path: JSON file to parse
    @return: parsed object as a dict
    """
    with open(path) as fh:
        return json.load(fh)
```

In this code, the initialization of `locales = []` is unnecessary,
because you assign to the variable in both branches of the `if`, so you can remove it:

> ```
>     locales = []
>     if setLocales:
>       locales = json.load(setLocales)
>     else:
>       lang_header = request.headers.get("Accept-Language", "en") # for example en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
>       locales = [locale.split(';')[0] for locale in lang_header.split(',')]
> ```